# How to create pdfTemplate without border in itext pdf Java? And also it extend to next page

Tags: java, pdf, itext, apache-poi

```
PdfTemplate template = cb.createTemplate(width, height);
template.addImage(bg, width, 0, 0, height-10, 0, 0);
template.addImage(signature, 39, 0, 0, 39, 15, height-50);
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(fontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font arabfont = new Font(bf, 8);
ColumnText.showTextAligned(template, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
    new Phrase("XXXXXXXXX",arabfont), 60, height-25, 0);
ColumnText.showTextAligned(template, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
    new Phrase("XXXXXXXXX", new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN  , 11, Font.BOLD)), 60, height-40, 0);
template.addImage(profileimg, 47, 0, 0, 55, (width/2)+60, (height/2)+10);
Integer h=20;
for (String detail : details) {
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(template, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
        new Phrase(detail, new Font(Font.HELVETICA  , 8, Font.BOLD)), 10, (height-40)-h, 0);
    h=h+10;
}
```

In this image has a template border ,that extended to next page.
[image]

Comment: How is `apache-poi` involved here?

Comment: The code you show does not create a border. Thus, you either have a border in the images you add or you create a border in code you don't show. Furthermore, templates only belong to the page they are added to. Thus, either you add the template to both pages or your pdf viewer has a bug.